# No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver in java 8.0

Tags: jdbc, sql-server-2012, java-8

I am using java 8.0 Eclipse Kepler IDE. I had used before SQL server 2012 with java 7.0 and it worked fine. However in java 8.0 I am getting problem to load the jdbc driver. Here are the step i have taken so far.

1. download sqljdbc42.jar from Microsoft web site in to the folder named as:
   `C:\Program Files\Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.2 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_4.2\enu`
2. than I have defined the `CLASSPATH` variable in the windows environment:
   `CLASSPATH =.;C:\Program Files\Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.2 for SQL Server\sqljdbc_4.2\enu\sqljdbc42.jar`
3. Than I have included the sqljdbc42.jar file into my Eclipse project using 
   buildpath->configure build path->Java buildpath. Here I have selected the external jar file and included the sqljdbc42.jar.

Then i have used following code:

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;" + "databaseName=AdventureWorks;integratedSecurity=true;";
System.out.println("using drive manager for connection");
con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl)
```

However  i have been unlucky to get connected with SQL server 2012.I have  got following Classnotfound exception error:

> No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver

Any suggestion what I am doing wrong? .

Comment: Most probably unrelated: in general setting `CLASSPATH` system wide is a **very** bad idea (and is strongly discouraged). You only need to include the jar file in the Eclipse project (I actually would be surprised if the `CLASSPATH` setting had any effect in Eclipse in the first place)

Comment: Another thing: you are using `integratedSecurity=true;` which means the JDBC driver will need to load the native DLL that is used to access the Windows user credentials. You need to make sure that that DLL is accessible in `java.library.path` **and** that this library is the 64bit or 32bit DLL depending on the JVM you are using. If you are using a 64bit JVM, that DLL must be 64bit as well. If you are using a 32bit JVM, the DLL must be 32bit.

Comment: I did tried to used without integrated security option giving following url
jdbc:sqlserver://ML-00107779\\MSSQLSERVER;DatabaseName=tempoDB;user=sa;password=‌​‌​123
 however i still received the SQL Exception: No suitable driver found

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your advice,I have sorted out my problem, now SQL server is connected. The problem was solved by adding the path of the sqljdbc_4.2.jar in to eclipse classpath. i  used run->runconfiguration->classpath and there i added sqljdbc_4.2.jar with its full path and it solved my problems. thanks for your support